# Is it possible to make Google show the normal page in the search results instead of the mobile page?

Tags: mobile, google-search

We have a separate mobile site and a separate desktop site. There's basically a "mobile" page for each normal page like this:

public_html/home.php
public_html/m/home.php

And the m/home.php is showing up in the search results. Is it possible to make google show the normal home.php instead?

Responsive design is a good solution, but that's not the answer I am looking for at the moment.

And I don't want to 301 redirect m/home.php because people on mobile still need to view it.

Is my only option to redirect the user to home.php from m/home.php when I detect that they are not using a mobile browser?

Answer (score 0):

My advice put noindex meta on your all mobile pages that's help you to prevent mobile pages getting result on Google serp then add mobile detection script on your normal site set and redirct for mobile users.